# UWSGI no fresh mysql query result or SP

Tags: python, mysql, nginx, uwsgi, flask-restful

Actually im learning about python, flask and mysql.

I build a restful api, with this code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import mysql.connector
from flask_cors import CORS
from db import ObtenerMarcaciones, ObtenerRelojes

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
CORS(app, support_credentials=True)

#coneccion BD
try:
    db = mysql.connector.connect(user='XXX',
                                 password='XXx',
                                 host='XXX',
                                 database='rrhhMarcaciones')
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Error en usuario y/o clave")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print('La BD no existe')
    else:
        print(err)

class Marcaciones(Resource):
    def get(self):

        data = ObtenerMarcaciones()
        return jsonify(data)

def ObtenerMarcaciones():
json_data = []
try:
    cursor = db.cursor(buffered=True)
    idreloj = ([1])
    cursor.callproc('SP_TodasMarcaciones', idreloj)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    json_data = {'Error': str(err)}
else:
    headers = {'MARCACION', 'USUARIO', 'CI'}
    for p_resultado in cursor.stored_results():
        pMarcaciones = p_resultado.fetchall()
    for element in pMarcaciones:
        json_data.append(dict(zip(headers, element)))
finally:
    cursor.close()

return json_data
```

The API, is in nginx with UWSGI working whithout issue, BUT

The API, shows always the same result of the query or SP, until i restart the UWSGI service.

Example: if i add some data to the tables that the API is fetching the data, i will never get via the API, until i restart the UWSGI service.

My UWSGI config file:

```
module = wsgi:app
logger = file:/home/flask_api/AsistenciaAPI/logs/uwsgi_AsistenciaAPI.log
master = true
processes = 5
socket = /home/flask_api/AsistenciaAPI/AsistenciaAPI.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

I appreciate any HELP!
Thanks!

Comment: could you please recheck the indentation of the code.

It seems wrong

The following two lines should provoke an error:
`def ObtenerMarcaciones():` followed by `json_data = []`

There must be an indentation after the `def ...`

If the indentation is not 100% correct it doesn't make sense to analyse the question as some indentation issue might be the reason for your issue.

Comment: another comment: Shouldn't your code abort if the database doesn't exist?
you just print an error, but don't abort. perhaps you should add a `raise` at the end of your except section?